# How to write linq query for xml in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I want to write a link query for my xml. Actually i dont know it.
i have write some code here.

```
 Dim query = _
     From p In MyPermissionXml.Elements("menuNode").Descendants("menuNode") _
         Where p.Attributes("title").ToString = "Company"
```

from where clause , i think it's wrong. how to represent an attribute here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change Attributes to Attribute and ToString to Value and you should be there

```
Dim query = _ 
    From p In MyPermissionXml.Elements("menuNode").Descendants("menuNode") _ 
        Where p.Attribute("title").Value = "Company"
```

Comment: do you have any tutorial for this subject-Linq Query??

Comment: @Vibin - not specifically no. Learnt mine from a combination of reading Linq in Action (manning), and of actually doing stuff with reference to numerous blogs etc.